# insercion de datos con web services php y Mysql

Tags: php, webservice, php7

Tengo un WS que consulta, actualiza, elimina datos pero cuando inserta arroja dos errores

`Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':title, :status, :content, :user_id)' at line 1 in C:\Apache24\htdocs\ws\post.php on line 37`

`( ! ) PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':title, :status, :content, :user_id)' at line 1 in C:\Apache24\htdocs\ws\post.php on line 37`

Se que es por que no esta llenando los datos con el método que tengo, pero uso ese mismo método para la actualización y si funciona, no se que me falta, no soy muy experto en php ni WS, este es la función que toma los datos

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
$input = $_POST;
$sql = "INSERT INTO posts (title, status, content, user_id) VALUES (:title, :status, :content, :user_id)";
$statement = $dbConn->prepare($sql);
bindAllValues($statement, $input);
$statement->execute();
$postId = $dbConn->lastInsertId();
if($postId)
{
  $input['id'] = $postId;
  header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
  echo json_encode($input);
  exit();
 }
}
```

y esta la función que los coloca en la sentencia

```
//Asociar todos los parametros a un sql
function bindAllValues($statement, $params){
foreach($params as $param => $value)
{
    $statement->bindValue(':'.$param, $value);
}
return $statement;
}
```

Tengo php 7 y apache2
Gracias

Comment: Ya vi el error pero no entiendo el por que, el error esta en la linea 2 $input = $_POST; debe venir con GET, si alguien me puede explicar, creo que es por que GET envía parámetros por URL, pero no me cuadra con el método por el que se ejecuta el WS, si alguien sabe le agradezco

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya vi el error pero no entiendo el por que, el error esta en la linea 2

```
$input = $_POST;
```

debe venir con GET, si alguien me puede explicar, creo que es por que GET envía parámetros por URL, pero no me cuadra con el método por el que se ejecuta el WS, si alguien sabe le agradezco

Comment: Es una respuesta entonces a la pregunta?

Comment: La pregunta es por que si el REQUEST_METHOD == 'POST', la entrada tiene que ser GET, eso es lo que me confunde y no se si es por lo que decía, es decir que relación tiene lo uno con lo otro

Comment: entonces esto debe ir como edición a tu pregunta

Comment: @BetaM, tu sabes la explicación a eso??